# Use theano in a macbook pro without NVIDIA card

Tags: macos, theano, osx-yosemite

I have:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
- OS X Yosemite
- Intel Iris 1536MB

I heard that I can not use GPU theano but CPU I do, but I want to know if the programming will be the same and internaly theano will work with CPU or in anothe case with GPU. Or if when I programming I have one way to program for each one.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part a Theano program that runs well on a CPU will also run well on a GPU, with no changes to the code required. There are, however, a few things to bear in mind.

- Not all operations have GPU versions so it's possible to create a computation that contains a component that cannot run on the GPU at all. When you run one of these computations on a GPU it will silently fall back to the CPU, so the program will run without failing and the result will be correct, but the computation is not running as efficiently as it might and will be slower because it has to copy data backwards and forwards between main and GPU memory.
- How you access your data can affect GPU performance quite a lot but has little impact on CPU performance. Main memory tends to be larger than GPU memory so it's often the case that your entire dataset can fit in main memory but not in GPU memory. There are techniques that can be used to avoid this problem but you need to bear in mind the GPU limitations in advance.

If you stick to conventional neural network techniques, and follow the patterns used in the Theano sample/tutorial code, then it will probably run fine on the GPU since this is the primary use-case for Theano.

Comment: In other words the code that I have can be performed in my mac without a NVIDIA card (no GPU) and my windows with NVIDIA card (it has GPU) with no changes in the code. But the velocity will be very different in most of the function I use. right?

Comment: Yes. But if you do something unusual it could end up running slower on a powerful GPU than on a mainstream CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, effectively Theano understand if you have GPU or not, and decide to use CPU or GPU to create variables, the only difficult is that when you create a model and variables with Theano with or without GPU config of variables change, in other words if you create a model with GPU (or CPU) and save them in a *.pickle (e.g.) and you go to another pc without CPU (or GPU respectively) this model and their variables saved will not work.